# Calculus-probability

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I have been working on a problem that needs to be proved.  Then, in the middle of the proof I was blocked because I could not upper bound this probability given bellow. Actually, the double sum of the first term in the absolute value is a problem because I could not expend it.

$$ \mathbb{P}\left\lbrace \left| \sum\limits_{\substack{i}}^{} {\sum\limits_{\substack{ j}}^{}{}} \chi[x_{i}\thicksim x_{j}]^{2} \left(  \dfrac{1}{ \mathbf{N}(x_{i})\mathbf{N}(x_{j})}- \dfrac{1}{ a_{n}^2} \right)  \right| > \dfrac{tn}{4} \right\rbrace,$$

Note that ${\sum\limits_{\substack{ j}}^{}{}} \chi[x_{i}\thicksim x_{j}]^{2}=\mathbf{N}(x_{i}).$

I want to end up with terms like $\sum\limits_{\substack{i}}^{} \mathbf{N}(x_{i}) $ or $\mathbf{N}(x_{i})$ but not $\sum\limits_{\substack{i}}^{} \dfrac{1}{\mathbf{N}(x_{i})}.$

If anyone can help with this, please let me know.

Thank you very much.

Comment: At a glance, couldn't the triangle inequality help?

Comment: I already tried this $\left|\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\right|\leqslant \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|.$